# var = str creates 'ambiguous use of appendingPathComponent' error

Tags: swift

I am working on a decibel measuring app for my class, and I have been stumped by an error that keeps on coming up: 'ambiguous use of appendingPathComponent'.  Here is where the problem is occurring:

//set up the URL for the audio file

```
    var documents: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,  FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0] as AnyObject
    var str = documents.appendingPathComponent("recordTest.caf")
    var url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: str as String)
```

The error is happening here:

```
   var str = documents.appendingPathComponent("recordTest.caf")
```

I can't seem to get this resolved.

Help,
Paul

Comment: Why do you annotate / cast `AnyObject` although you (are supposed to) know exactly that `String` is returned? **Do not annotate types the compiler can infer anyway**.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you casting `documents` to `AnyObject`? Get rid of that.

But that then brings up a new issue since `appendingPathComponent` is a method of `NSString`, `NSURL`, or `URL`. But `documents` is a `String`.

And why use `NSURL` instead of `URL`?

Since your goal is to get a `URL`, use the more direct approach with `FileManager`:

```
let docURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let url = docURL.appendingPathComponent("recordTest.caf")
```

Comment: try! it is bad practice

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Yes, normally it is. You can certainly update this code to use `do/catch` or consider that the user's Documents folder will always be there and this won't fail.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk `try!` is a good practice if it's guaranteed that the *attempt* cannot fail (like in this case).

Comment: So is the error the 'var' or the AnyObject lines above that?  In XCODE 8  this is the only error that is preventing me from creating a build.

Comment: Definitely the AnyObject.

Comment: @rmaddy ok. I'll give that a whirl and see what happens. Thanks much.